# Passing a pointer of a structure from a function to another function

Tags: c, function, structure

I have a structure of structures which is global. I am using functions to change the data of the structure. 
In general I manipulate the structure easily (e.g. send it to a function).
My problem is that now I have a function that changes the data of the structure, but it also has to call another function. And this is my problem.

In general my structure is the: "name".
I have a pointer: name_ptr->name[i]....
In case of a function I am passing it like this:
    `find_max = calc_max(i, &name_ptr);`
and this function id declared as: 
`int find_max(int x, vectname **pr)`
So inside the function I am working like this:
`(*pr)->name[i]...`
If I am into the function and I want to sent this pointer to another function how can I call it?

Comment: Simple call `nextFunction(pr)`. The definition should be `nextFunction(vectname **arg){}`

Comment: A "structure of structures" is something worth showing. Do try and remember you can see *all* your existing code; we can see precisely *none* of it. Strip it down to the specific point you're having a problem choosing the right syntax and *post it*. As-is one needs a pick-axe night-goggles, and a compass to navigate this question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In simple words you have an array of structures and to your first function you get the pointer to the array.

So either you can use:

```
int find_max(int x, vectname **pr)
{

  //  method - 1 (if your second function is intreseted only in changing the nth structure instance of the array )
   SecondFunc( &pr[n]);

  //  method - 2 (if your second function is intreseted in changing the any structure instance of the array )
   SecondFunc( pr );

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your question is quite cryptic but i'll give it a shot:

```
int find_max(int x, vectname **pr)
{
  ...
  another_function(x, pr);
  ...
}
```